# Calling an API in a Docker container from a different Docker container (same host, Apache)

Tags: php, apache, docker, networking

Situation:

I have 2 docker containers running both Symfony 4 applications. cte_app and cte_fe. cte_app is exposed to port 8080 on the host and cte_fe to port 80.

cte_app contains API methods which I need to consume with cte_fe. I can consume the API from cte_app on the host machine just fine (using Postman) but not via cte_fe in a PHP function using cURL, I get a connection refused error (using localhost:8080 and container-name (which is dependant)). When I use the Docker's gateway address I can consume the API from the cte_fe container just fine. But I can't guarantee that the gateway address won't change over time.

What is the preferred way to call an API endpoint between 2 containers living on the same host? Is there some flag I have missed in the documentation which exposes the gateway address to the container as an environment variable?

```
version: '3'
services:

cte_db:
    image: mysql:5.7.24
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: cte_db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /cte_data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepassword
        MYSQL_DATABASE: somedatabase
        MYSQL_USER: someuser
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: somepassword

cte_apache:
    build: .docker/apache
    container_name: cte_apache
    ports:
       - 8080:8080
       - 80:80
    volumes:
       - .docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
       - ./cte_app:/home/wwwroot/cte_app
       - ./cte_fe:/home/wwwroot/cte_fe
    depends_on:
       - cte_fe
       - cte_app

cte_app:
    build: .docker/php
    container_name: cte_app
    volumes:
       - ./cte_app:/home/wwwroot/cte_app
    depends_on:
       - cte_db

cte_fe:
    build: .docker/php
    container_name: cte_fe
    volumes:
      - ./cte_fe:/home/wwwroot/cte_fe
    depends_on:
      - cte_app
      - cte_db
```

Comment: *'What is the preferred way'* It might be important whether the containers are guaranteed to run on the same machine forever or the project could be scaled to run distributed as well. Personally, I would prefer to develop in a scalable way. However, there might be performance improvements on having local connections only. I'm not a docker expert.

Answer (score 2):

For one container to reach another in a context like this, you can use the service name in the `docker-compose.yml` file as a host name, and the TCP port number the process inside the container is listening on as a port number.  The port doesn't specifically need to be exposed or published, and you don't need to manually set `container_name:`.  Docker Compose will handle the Docker-level networking machinery for you.

It is often beneficial to make this configurable, maybe through an environment variable, which also supports cases like non-Docker development and service-discovery systems like Consul or Kubernetes Services.

If "fe" stands for "front end" and the connection is actually being made from a browser app, you must consider this from the point of view of the browser: none of these Docker details exist at all, and if you must use absolute URLs, you need to use the host's DNS name or IP address and the published port of the server.  Given what you've shown that's probably the Apache proxy and you'd use URLs like `http://my.host.dns.name:8080/app`.